# Why is no qualification necessary?

Tags: c++

OK, I'll just post the complete program even though it has extraneous stuff and the code in question is the dead code…

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace detail {
    // Solution by Johannes Schaub alias litb
    // http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/b567617bfccabcad
    template<int> struct D {};
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template< class T, class U >
    yes& f( int, D< sizeof T(*(U*)0) >* = 0 );

    template< class T, class U >
    no& f( ... );

    template< class To, class From >
    struct IsExplicitlyConvertible
    {
        enum{ yes = (sizeof detail::f< To, From >(0) == sizeof( detail::yes ) ) };
    };

    bool const streamsSupportWindows =
        IsExplicitlyConvertible< std::ofstream, wchar_t const* >::yes;
}

class InFStream
    : public std::ifstream
{
    public:
        InFStream() {}
        explicit InFStream(
            char const* filename,
            ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out
            )
            : std::ifstream( filename, mode )
        {}
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << (detail::streamsSupportWindows
        ? "Windows-enabled"
        : "Ach, no Windows support"
        ) << endl;
}
```

This compiles fine with MSVC and g++. But in the `InFStream` class, why do I not need to qualify `ios_base`? Or, same question really, why do I need to use `std::` qualification of `ifstream` in the constructor initializer list?

Comment: Because `ifstream` is in the std namespace? Why do you think you do not need to use it?

Comment: @VJo: `ios_base` is also in the `std` namespace. As to why I think that the compilers I mention compile this code just fine, that's because they do. Heh.

Comment: Possibly because your InFStream class inherits from std::ifstream which in turn inherits from std::ios_base. So all the ios_base enumerations are members of your class via inheritance and do not need full qualification.

Comment: @Praetorian: why does He need to use `std::` qualification of `ifstream` in the constructor initializer list in that case?

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: you can remove `ios_base::` too. (Don't know why though.)

Comment: @Als I didn't realize we use capital letters when referring to AlfP :-P I don't know the answer to your question, which is why I deleted the answer and posted it as a comment. A guess - the name lookup rules differ somehow when it comes to the class you're inheriting from and the members you're inheriting via said class.

Comment: @Praetorian: I thought so,was hoping you would add a Standard quote, maybe you should give the Holy book a look seems what you think might be *it*.Yeah you know AlfP is so senior He deserves an caps ovation :)

Comment: Should probably change the question and ask, why the qualification *is* necessary for the call to the base constructor.

Comment: I should point out hat my code has a flaw. It will think that `T*` is constructible from an `int`, because for non-class types, the `type(e)` construct is just equivalent to a cast. To go safe, you could check whether the type is a class, and if not, then fall-back to `is_convertible`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some thoughts about why you have to specify `std::ifstream` in constructor's initializer .
I think `typedef` is the culprit - `ifstream` is defined as `typedef basic_ifstream<char, char_traits<char> > ifstream;`).  If you change your constructor to

```
 explicit InFStream(
    char const*         filename,
    ios_base::openmode  mode =  ios_base::in | ios_base::out

    ):
    basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>( filename, mode ){}
```

you also don't have to specify `std::basic_ifstream`. I cannot find details about why `typedef` works this way, but the problem is reproducible. For instance,

```
namespace test1
{
class A {

public :
    static const int cn = 1;

    virtual ~A();
    A(int t): x(t){};
    int x;
};

class B:public A
{
public:
    B(int t) : A(t){};
};
typedef B XX;  
};  
class C:public test1::XX
{
  int aaa;
    public:
explicit  C(int x) :XX(x) // error  
explicit  C(int x) :test1::XX(x) // ok
explicit  C(int x) :B(x) // also ok
{       
    aaa = A::cn;
};
};
```

Comment: I had to select a bit arbitrarily which answer is "the solution", but I think this answer was the first one to point out the `typedef` issue.

Comment: And to add, you can just write `: basic_ifstream(filename, mode) {}`. No need for the template argument list (and starting from gcc4.5, gcc finally gets this correctly).

Answer (score 7):

The difference is that `ifstream` isn't visible as an injected class name because it is the name of a `typedef`, not the name of the `class`. It isn't therefore visible unqualified as an injected class name from the base class.

`ios_base` is a genuine class name which is a base class (of a base class) of the class where it is used and so is visible unqualified as an inject class name.

E.g.

```
namespace X
{
    class A {};
    template<class> class Z {};
    typedef Z<char> B;
}

class C : public X::A
{
    C() : A() {} // OK, A is visible from the base class
};

class D : public X::B
{
    D() : B() {} // Error, B is a typedef,
    // : X::B(), : Z<char>() or even : Z() can be used.
};
```

In your example, instead of `std::ifstream`, you can use unqualified `basic_ifstream` instead. (Or `basic_ifstream<char>` or `basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >` but these don't really save any typing or help clarity at all.)

Answer (score 4):

Another observation is that ios_base::openmode works, but ios::openmode does not:

```
class InFStream
    : public std::ifstream
{
    // ...
    ios::openmode m1;       // error: ios does not name a type
    ios_base::openmode m2;  // ok
}
```

I think a1ex07 has found the crux of the matter: here again, `ios_base` is the name of a class, while `ios` is merely a typedef.

And the difference is that the name of a class is a member of that class (9/2), and so can be looked up as the name of the type in `InFStream` (3.4.1/7 item 1) as it is a member of a base class of `InFStream`.  But some typedef merely alongside the base class off in some other namespace can't be seen.

[Standard section numbers from C++98.]

Answer (score 0):

When you derive from the class you have specify

```
std::ifstream
```

to be able to find the class in the std namespace.

In the code itself you class derived from std::ifstream knows everything of ifstream.

Inheritance of ifstream:

```
ios_base -> ios -> istream -> ifstream
```

Comment: What of `ios_base`? It also lives in the `std` namespace.