# Do invocations of std constructors need to be qualified?

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, constructor, namespaces

Do invocations of `std` constructors need to be qualified with `std::`?

```
class whatever : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    explicit whatever(const std::string& what) : runtime_error(what) {}
};                                            // ^ do I need std:: here?
```

It works on my compiler without the qualification, but I'm not sure whether that behavior is standard.

Comment: Basically, you're asking if you can refer to base classes without qualification (not necessarily `std`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you don't. The names in the initializer list are looked up in the scope of the `whatever` class. This class scope includes names declared in base classes and the name of the base class (`runtime_error`) is inserted into the scope of `std::runtime_error` (this is standard behaviour for all classes).

Note that this doesn't work if the name that you use is a `typedef` for the actual class name. You can easily be tempted with, e.g., `std::istream` and friends. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868009/why-is-no-qualification-necessary)

Comment: See C++2003, §9.2, for the definition of "*injected-class-name*".

Comment: @Robᵩ: Thanks, I don't have my standard to hand. :o

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the qualification in the initializer list (to be honest I don't know if the qualification is even allowed there), as it is a base and will be found by lookup through the class.